# WPF DataGridHyperlinkColumn: hiding or showing hyperlink depending on a condition

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an WPF MVVM app. In the main WPF window, I have a WPF datagrid which has some columns. One of them is of type DataGridHyperlinkColumn. This column contains a link which does some stuff on user click.

The datagrid is bound to a data model class, let's say MyDataGridModel (I am only showing here the necessary objects to understand my case) :

```
public class MyDataGridModel : NotifyBase
{
   // Properties, members, methods, etc.

   public MyLinkData myLinkData { get; set; }
}
```

The DataGridHyperlinkColumn column is bound to a  data model, let's say **MyLinkData**:

**MyLinkData**:

```
public class MyLinkData
{
    private string linkText = string.Empty;
    private string linkValue = string.Empty;

    public string LinkText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.linkText;
        }

        private set
        {
            if (!this.linkText.Equals(value))
            {
                this.linkText = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string LinkValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.linkValue;
        }

        private set
        {
            if (!this.linkValue.Equals(value))
            {
                this.linkValue = value;
            }
        }
    }

    #region Constructors

    public MyLinkData(string linkText, string linkValue)
    {
        this.LinkText = linkText;
        this.LinkValue = linkValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**View**:

```
<my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn 
                            Binding="{Binding myLinkData.LinkValue}" 
                            ContentBinding="{Binding myLinkData.LinkText}">
    <my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">                
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnCellHyperlinkClick" />
        </Style>
    </my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    <my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="my:DataGridCell">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myLinkData.LinkValue}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
</my:DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

This link is disabled when link value contains an empty string and enabled otherwise.

Now, what I would like to do is to hide the link when link value contains an empty string instead of making it disabled. So how can I do this?

I was thinking of changing link color to make it not visible but then I may take into account when the row is selected (color is blue) and some other things making things more difficult (in my case rows also change color depending on some conditions).

Comment: Did you try <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" /> under that isenabled setter in the datatrigger?

Comment: @Andy Yes, I have tried, but compiler throws below error: PropertyDescriptor value is not valid. Note: I am using VS2008 and NET 3.5.

Comment: I have not solved this yet. If someone could help me, suggestions are always welcome.